# Query items in a dictionary in a CosmosDB document

Tags: c#, sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have documents like this in my CosmosDB database:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "filename": "foo.txt",
    "versions": {
        "1": {
            "storageAccount": "blob123",
            "size": 33
        },
        "2": {
            "storageAccount": "blob123",
            "size": 42
        }
    }
}
```

(this is a simplified sample)

I need to query on the `"storageAccount"` property, to check if there are files stored on a given storage account. But I can't find a way to express "for each version".

I tried this, but of course it doesn't work

```
select top 1 *
from c
join v in c.versions
where v.storageAccount = 'blob123'
```

Apparently `JOIN` only works on arrays, not dictionaries. Is there a way to query items in a dictionary?

As a workaround, I can use an UDF, but the performance and cost are terrible (1200 RUs for just 2000 documents when there is not matching document...)

*EDIT: updated to more closely reflect actual use case*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible today. You cannot iterate over object keys in Cosmos's SQL.

I'd recommend changing the schema to something like:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "filename": "foo.txt",
    "versions": [
        {
            "id": "1"
            "storageAccount": "blob123",
            "size": 33
        },
        {
            "id": "2"
            "storageAccount": "blob123",
            "size": 42
        }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, you could evaluate a User Defined Function which would return the keys of an object for you, but that will increase your RU costs, though possibly less than sprocs.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's what I ended up doing did. A UDF-based solution isn't viable, as it needs to perform a full scan of the collection

Comment: Me too have exactly same kind of model mentioned above dictionary format & this model is being used for such long time in my proj. so way I can remodel it & UDF approach not preferred. Is there any better way of querying dictionary object using linq using "Values" property? my original query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451606/querying-complex-nested-object-in-cosmosdb-using-sql-api