# Querying complex nested object in cosmosdb using sql Api

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How query only those users whose Itemcount > 10 from the complex nested object(with dynamic key) from comosdb using sql api? UDF not preferred.

Something like,

Select c.username from c where  c.Data[*].Order.ItemCount  > 10;

```
 {
  {
    "Username": "User1",
    "Data": {
        "RandomGUID123": {
                "Order": {               
                    "Item": "ItemName123",
                    "ItemCount" : "40"
                },
                "ShipmentNumber": "7657575"
            },
        "RandomGUID976": {
                "Order": {               
                    "Item": "ItemName7686"
                    "ItemCount" : "7"
                },
                "ShipmentNumber": "876876"
             }
          }
  },     
  {
    "Username": "User2",
    "Data": {
        "RandomGUID654": {
            "Order": {               
                "Item": "ItemName654",
                "ItemCount" : "9"
            },
            "ShipmentNumber": "7612575"
        },
        "RandomGUID908": {
            "Order": {               
                "Item": "ItemName545"
                "ItemCount" : "6"
            },
            "ShipmentNumber": "6454"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way other than the below suggestions? without UDF & without remodeling the above mentioned data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how to handle unknown keys, but if you're willing to model the key as a value instead (simpler and cleaner I'd argue), you could have:

```
{
    "Username": "User1",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Id": "RandomGUID123",
            "Order": {
                "Item": "ItemName123",
                "ItemCount": 40
            },
            "ShipmentNumber": "7657575"
        },
        {
            "Id": "RandomGUID976",
            "Order": {
                "Item": "ItemName7686",
                "ItemCount": 7
            },
            "ShipmentNumber": "876876"
        }
    ]
}
```

With a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE(c.Username) 
FROM c
JOIN (SELECT VALUE d from d IN c.Data where d["Order"].ItemCount > 10)
```

Result:

```
[
    "User1"
]
```

"Order" is a reserved keyword and requires the bracket syntax to reference.

Comment: remodeling is not an option, as real "Id" field have some reserved special chars like " /RandomIdGuid" which cosmos db wont accept as "Key" field.

Comment: Isn't that another reason to store as property value instead?

Comment: I'm wrong but you are right with above statement. Still remodeling is not an option it is exiting model for more than couple of years and many many logic revolves around this model.

Comment: A compromise could be to store an additional property on the document that is the calculated result you want to query, like UserItemCount. Then keep that value updated in whatever logic performs writes or maintenance jobs. This wouldn't affect any existing logic.

Comment: Basically Im looking for query to filter dictionary object(i.e., "Data" property in the example) by item value not by key, as key is dynamic in my case

Comment: Understood. This model seems fundamentally flawed, because there's nothing to gain from pulling a property out of an object to make it an unknown key when you need to query into the object. Curious to see if you ever find a way to do this without remodel.

Comment: Linq is supporting to dictionary filter using "Values" property but it not returning results. Dont know the reason.

Comment: LINQ is a C# construct, not a Cosmos construct. LINQ can express more possibilities than can actually be translated into Cosmos queries, which is what the SDK does. Unless you can write the query text directly, don't assume your LINQ query is meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

As Noah answers,model the key as a value is a way to achieve.

Additionally,there is another way to achieve without changing your schema of your document .Create UDF like this:

```
function getResult(data){
  for(var key in data){
    const itemCount = data[key].Order.ItemCount;
    if (parseFloat(itemCount).toString() != "NaN" && parseFloat(itemCount) > 10 ) {
　　　　return true;
　　}
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then run this sql:

```
SELECT c.Username FROM c where udf.getResult(c.Data)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "Username": "User1"
    }
]
```