# Cosmos DB query without knowing the key for object

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Single document example:

```
{
  "id" : "xxxxxx",
  "properties": {
      "a_prop": {
        type: "names",
        value: "John",
      },
      "b_prop": {
        type: "score",
        value: 5.5,
      },
      "c_prop": {
        type: "names",
        value: "Steve",
      }
   }
}
```

Question - how can I get documents that has at least one property with type "names" ?
Struggle is that I cannot know before that property "a_prop" is a type of "names".

Answer (score 1):

It's no fun to query when your model has collections of objects with unknown, arbitrary keys. Consider changing model to have known keys and store the unknowns as property values. For example, changing `properties` to an array of items:

```
{
  id: "xxxxxx",
  properties: [
    {
        name: "a_prop",
        type: "names",
        value: "John",
    },
    {
        name: "b_prop",
        type: "score",
        value: 5.5,
    },
    {
        name: "c_prop",
        type: "names",
        value: "Steve",
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the [array-based query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) for items with a property of type "names":

```
SELECT * FROM c 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.properties, {"type": "names"}, true)
```

See also discussion for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451606/querying-complex-nested-object-in-cosmosdb-using-sql-api/63459762#63459762).